# Inserting images in report class document

Tags: graphics

I am writing a thesis report, and would like to insert images. A majority of the images that I am using are high resolution bitmap. I am using the following to insert the images

```
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{refstyle}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[H]

        \graphicspath{ {Chapter1Images/} }
        \centering
        \includegraphics{logo}
        \caption{Typical Moment-Resisting Frame Deformation}
        \label{fig:ch1deformedframe}

    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

This works exactly as I want it to if I put in a basic PNG image, but as soon as I attempt to insert a high resolution bitmap image I get an error saying it cannot find the file. Is there a special way you must go about inserting bitmap-type images?

Comment: And what kind of file are you trying to include, precisely?

Comment: @jon its just a .bmp file. I have it located in the same folder as the .png. but the png will insert to my document while the bmp gives me an error

Comment: @RyanG pdftex can not include bmp, you can losslessly convert it to png first.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oh, well that is disappointing. Thank you for clearing it up. There is no package you can install to make Latex accept bitmap?

Comment: @RyanG The binary determines what files can be included. The best a package can do is on-the-fly conversion.

Comment: png is a bitmap (which is why your question was confusing until you clarified it in comments) to include a bmp format bitmap into pdf _something_ would have to convert it so rather than bloat pdftex by including every kind of image convertor it includes png for bitmaps and jpg for lossy compressed images and leaves conversion to those formats to external programs

Comment: @DavidCarlisle okay thanks for the clarification. Inserting the same image as png seems to work so I will just export all images as png instead of bmp to simplify things

Comment: `graphicx` can do conversion on-the-fly if you tell it the rules. This is what it does with `.eps` for example, converting to `.pdf`.